# how do i access my root folders, through my php script?

Tags: php

i have this include function in a file inside another folder called ajax, but it wnt let me access this include file:

```
include("includes/connect.php");
```

i dont know what to do, thanks, and im using localhost?

```
Warning: include(includes/connect.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\final\ajax\moreProfileUpdates.php on line 2
```

Comment: i put the error in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `include()` function is trying to locate ajax/includes/connect.php, which doesn't exist.
Try changing it to:

```
// assumes 'includes' directory is one directory up from the 'ajax' directory
include '../includes/connect.php';
```

Comment: Alternatively the OP can set a proper [`include_path`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)